$A$-twist and the stress-energy tensor
This is a horribly long question about the very basic thing: the definition of the $A$-twist (of, say, a SUSY-sigma model).
There are two parts. In the first one, I am just asking what this definition is in terms of the spin connection on the source surface.
In the second one, I am asking how the $A$-twist changes the stress-energy tensor. My main struggle is that the standard answer contains the variation of the correlation function with respect to the gauge-field for the axial symmetry.
But there is no this gauge field in the Lagrangian so I do not understand what variation are people talking about.
To elaborate.
I. In the "Mirror symmetry" book by Hori, Vafa, et al. (available on the web, Section 16.2), the $A$-twist of the theory is introduced in a rather ad hoc way:

<After the Wick rotation, the counterpart of> the SO(1, 1) Lorentz group is the Euclidean rotation group $SO(2)_E$ = $U(1)_E$. <...> We consider a theory that possesses either one of $U(1)_V$ or $U(1)_A$ $R$-symmetries under which the R-charges are all integral, and the diagonal subgroup $U(1)_E^{'}$ of $U(1)_E × U(1)_R$.

In what follows, $U(1)_R$ will be $U(1)_A$, the axial rotation of fermions: $\psi_{\pm} \to e^{\mp\alpha}\psi_{\pm}$, and we will work with some theory (say, $\sigma$-model) on a curved worldsheet (say, $S$).

The twisted theory <...> is obtained by gauging the new
rotation group $U(1)_E^{'}$ (instead of the one $U(1)_E$) by the spin connection <of $S$>.


What this means is that the fields will now be sections of different bundles
over the Riemann surface, i.e., the “spins” of the fields are modified.

They list the new spins of the particles (e.g., $\psi_-$ now corresponds to the section of the trivial line bundle $\mathbb C$ instead of $\sqrt{K}$ to which the spinor should naturally belong). Thus, the second (i.e., ``what this means'')-phrase indeed gives a recipe to write down an explicit Lagrangian for the $A$-twist of a given theory.
However, the first phrase is non-clear for me.
What does the ``gauging of the rotation group by the spin connection mean'', and why this operation changes the nature of the fields?
II. This is important in the following place. Let $h$ be the metric on $S$. In 16.2.2, the stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ is introduced by the formula
$$\delta_h \langle \mathcal O \rangle = \langle \mathcal O \frac{1}{4\pi} \int 
\sqrt{h} \ d^2x \  \delta_h^{µν}) \  T_{µν} \rangle$$
for an operator $\mathcal O$.
Now, they claim that
$$T_{\mu\nu}^{twisted} = T_{µν} + \frac{1}{4} (
\epsilon^{\lambda}_{\mu}\partial_{\lambda}J^R_\nu + \epsilon^{\lambda}_{\mu}\partial_{\lambda}J^R_\nu).$$
for $J_{\mu}^R$ defined as
$$\delta_{A^R} \langle \mathcal O \rangle = \langle O \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int *J^R \wedge \delta A^R \rangle$$
where $A^R$ is the gauge field for the $U(1)_A$-symmetry.
But, as far as I understand, this field does not enter the Lagrangian! Does it?
So the questions are.
A. How to make sense of the statement above? I.e., what is $\delta_{A^R} \langle \mathcal O \rangle$?
B. Why is this statement true? (I hope that this will be an exercise if someone will kindly explain the answer to the first part of my question.)
P. S. All of this should be about some statement of the form ``the axial $R$-symmetry gauge changes the gravity'' as in [1]. But I do not understand anything at this point!
